# Can an MD5-hash begin with a zero?

Tags: md5, zero

Can an MD5-hash begin with a zero? What about SHA-1?

Comment: A more interesting question would be whatever problem you're running into that made you ask this question in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're still around, but can I ask why you were asking about whether it can start with 0? I've run into a problem where the hash appears to be dropping leading result 0's and adding an F to the end :S

Comment: Just run into this question as my manager asked me to provide a test case of a hash value that contains a zero byte.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes:

```
$ echo -n "363" | md5sum
00411460f7c92d2124a67ea0f4cb5f85  -
$ echo -n "351" | sha1sum
0026476a20bfbd08714155bb66f0b4feb2d25c1c
```

Found by running the following in bash:

```
for i in  {1..1000} ; do echo $(echo -n $i | md5sum) $i ; done | sort | head
```

Answer (score 8):

Try with the string : jk8ssl

```
echo md5('jk8ssl')
```

generate :

```
00000000 18e6137a c2caab16 074784a6
```

I didn't find better yet ^^

Comment: have you found a better?

Comment: Kudos for finding an alphanumeric string. Very satisfying.

Answer (score 6):

I found a MD5 hash that beginns with a zero byte!
2 character String

Unicode
  #7358 #34823

```
$returnValue = md5('Ჾ蠇');
```

result:

```
00000000 5e0a51c8 313ffb43 8a3a2861
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course. Or two zeros. Or more. In general, the probability of a "random" input hashing to a result with k leading zero nybbles is about 2<sup>-4k</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

md5 of a = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661

```
<?php echo md5( 'a' ); ?>
```

Sha1 of i = 042dc4512fa3d391c5170cf3aa61e6a638f84342

```
<?php echo sha1( 'i' ); ?>
```

why not :D

Answer (score 2):

MD5 hash of "a" = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661

SHA1 hash of "9" = 0ade7c2cf97f75d009975f4d720d1fa6c19f4897

Answer (score 2):

In a cryptographic hash, any given bit should be equally likely to be a 0 or a 1 for random inputs.

Comment: But aren't there sometimes specific output formats associated with a hash algorithm? E.g. DES extended format starts and ends with an underscore.

Comment: Sure, but that's not part of the hash itself, it's just markup.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is pretty old now, but there are some very high & very low value hashes for SHA1 and MD5 here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20171201071711/http://www.crysys.hu/hashgame/allrecord.php

One of those has 7 bytes of leading zeros.

Comment: This link returns *404*

Comment: Thanks. Have switched link to the _wayback machine_