# MD5 hash with leading zeros

Tags: md5

does anybody of you know of a word, which MD5 hash has got 12 zeros?
So, i am looking for something like:

```
md5_hex(word)="000000000000...".
```

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close; asking to locate an "offsite resource". By definition, there are thousands of correct answers to this question.

Comment: Unclearly specified. What do you mean by "word"? An English word, any sequence of letters, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from hashlib import md5  
from base64 import b64decode

print md5(b64decode('Vf3ppC4Iu74AAAAAaHR0cDovL2hhc2hjYXQubmV0LwA=')).hexdigest()
```

0000000000006c32a237fc882cc44a4b

http://www.crysys.hu/hashgame/allrecord.php

Comment: this is cool, but are they generated by any code, or by tons of brute force?

Comment: Tons of brute force.

Answer (score 8):

`md5('j(R1wzR*y[^GxWJ5B>L{-HLETRD') = 0x00000000000003695b3ae70066f60d42`

Found it by GPU computing on NVIDIA Tesla K40c

Answer (score 4):

The best result I could find is `md5(jk8ssl)`, which gives a zero byte:

`00000000 18e6137a c2caab16 074784a6`

The original result was found by @delta14 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180374/can-an-md5-hash-begin-with-a-zero)

Comment: This one is particularly satisfying for being a simple alphanumeric text string

Answer (score 4):

One of the properties of a cryptographic hash-function (as *md5* is) is:

> Given any hash `t` it is difficult to find any message `m` where `hash(m) = t`. 
> In other words: a secure cryptographic hash-function must **not be invertible**.

So what you are requesting is not so easy to achieve. (even though *md5* is not considered secure anymore) You will probably have to do a brute-force search on your own:

```
/* pseudo-code */
desired = "00000000000000";

while (!hash(m).equals(desired)) // try as long as a message with desired hash is found
    m = nextMessage(); // try next message

print(m);
```

Comment: It should be hash(m).ToString.StartWith("000000000000") instead of a simple `!=`

Comment: Besides, your code can only find data types that are able to be iterated, such as integers and chars, but not for complex combinations, like strings.

Comment: That is correct, but it should actually only be pseudo-code. I have edited my post to make the code a bit better understandable though.